# flet equivalent of let*?

Tags: lisp, elisp

There is not an `flet*` for `flet` as there is `let*` for `let` that I can find in emacs lisp -- so are any of these four alternatives more idiomatic for defining a function used multiple times by a single function defined by `flet`? In this example, `add1` is the function that I want to reused within `add1twice` but not used outside of it.

Option 1

```
(defun add2 (x)
  (flet ((add1 (x) (1+ x)))
    (flet ((add1twice (x)
              (add1 (add1 x))))
      (add1twice x))))
```

Option 2

```
(defun add2 (x) 
  (flet ((add1twice (x)
            (flet ((add1 (x) (1+ x)))
              (add1 (add1 x)))))
     (add1twice x)))
```

Option 3

```
(defun add2 (x)
  (flet ((add1twice (x)
            (let (add1)
              (fset 'add1 (lambda (x) (1+ x)))
              (add1 (add1 x)))))
      (add1twice x)))
```

Option 4

```
(labels ((add1 (x) (1+ x)))
  (defun add2 (x) 
    (flet ((add1twice (x)
              (add1 (add1 x))))
      (add1twice x))))
```

(All of these produce the same results.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not too clear in [the documentation for `flet`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Function-Bindings.html), its macroexpansion reveals that it tolerates sequential binding:

```
(defun add2 (x)
  (flet ((add1 (x) (1+ x))
         (add1twice (x)
           (add1 (add1 x))))
    (add1twice x)))
```

The documentation mentions establishing "`let`-style bindings"—*not* `let*`—but the definition above works nonetheless.

Comment: Actually, `cl-flet` works in this case, by accident, only if your code is dynamically scoped.  With lexically scoped code, this doesn't work.

Comment: That's an interesting find. I'd like to see an example that shows it breaking, but the comments don't afford a good way to share code snippets.

Comment: Try your own example in a lexbind buffer, it will/should say `Symbol’s function definition is void: add1` when calling `(add2 6)`.

Answer (score 2):

You have also `labels` which is for `flet`, like `let*` is for `let`.

Comment: Actually `cl-labels` is not quite like `let*` either because it allows (mutually) recursive uses (IOW, it's more like `letrec`).  But indeed, I've never been in a situation where I needed a `cl-flet*` and where `cl-labels` didn't work just as well!

Answer (score 0):

BTW, besides the use of `cl-labels`, you can also do it "by hand" with `let*`:

```
(defun add2 (x)
  (let* ((add1 (lambda (x) (1+ x)))
         (add1twice (lambda (x) (funcall add1 (funcall add1 x)))))
    (funcall add1twice x)))
```

it's a bit more verbose than `cl-flet` and `cl-labels`, admittedly.